# django tastypie : Getting extra-values of a m2m relationships using intermediate model

Tags: django, many-to-many, tastypie, m2m

I'm trying to use Tastypie with **ManyToMany relationships** using **intermediate** models (**through** keyword) (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

I'm working with these models:

```
class Point(models.Model):
    ...
    value = models.FloatField(_('Value'), null=True)
    rooms = models.ManyToManyField('rooms.Room', through='points.PointPosition')

class Room(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)

class PointPosition(models.Model):
    point = models.ForeignKey('points.Point', verbose_name=_('Point'))
    room = models.ForeignKey('rooms.Room', verbose_name=_('Room'))
    x = models.IntegerField(_('Y'))
    y = models.IntegerField(_('X'))
```

I've been able to fetch the many-to-many relationship, but **not the extra fields**. Here's my tastypie code:

```
class PointResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Point.objects.select_related(
            depth=10
            ).prefetch_related('rooms').all()
        resource_name = 'point'
        allowed_methods = ['get']

    ...
    value = fields.FloatField()
    rooms = fields.ToManyField('rooms.api.RoomResource', 'rooms', full=True)

class RoomResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Room.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'room'
        allowed_methods = ['get']
```

I've been trying to use a method to **hydrate** the room variable in my **PointResource** like this:

```
def dehydrate_rooms(self, bundle):                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    rooms = []                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    for room in bundle.obj.rooms.all():                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        position = PointPosition.objects.get(                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            room_id = room.pk,                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
            point_id = bundle.obj.pk)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
        rooms.append({'id': room.pk,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
             'title': room.title,                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
             'x': position.x,                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
             'y': position.y})                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    return rooms
```

But the problem is that it creates as many query as I have points: it's a real **performance killer** when you have +8000 Points.

I haven't been able to find any useful resources to gain performance.
I was thinking of doing a custom query using the .extra() method available for QuerySet, but the JOIN keyword isn't available (the patch has been refused a couple months ago).
And I'm not sure SELECT subqueries would do the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you considered changing your queryset to use the `PointPosition` resource? From the sounds of it what "Point" means in your database isn't actually the same as what "Point" means in your API so there needs to be some translation to hide the internal details:

```
class PointResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = PointPosition.objects.select_related("point", "room")
        resource_name = 'point'
        allowed_methods = ('get', )
```

At the expense of needing to adjust your filtering parameters, this will avoid the need to do more than one query. Your `dehydrate` method can swap the data around as needed. You might also save some overhead by using `.values()` to only pull out the necessary fields as a dictionary rather than full objects.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.

That's in fact what I did, but I didn't think to use `dehydrate` to swap elements to reorder my dictionnary. Cool tip :)

Comment: I spent too much time fighting tastypie before reminding myself that it's just building a simple data structure and there wasn't a single right way to build a dictionary. I have at least one resource where a gnarly overridden ModelResource became a simple Resource which simply calls the ORM directly to efficiently build an intricate data structure.